# Chaining tasks of varying return types (TPL and HttpWebRequest)

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

Folks, I'm finding myself in a weird situation. I need to chain tasks of different returning types together. Normally, you can do something like this

```
Task<T> t = Task<T>.Factory.StartNew(() => ... some T instance);
Task t2 = t.ContinueWith<U>(parent => ...);
return Task.WhenAll(t, t2);
```

My complication however, lies in using the `FromAsync` helper method to wrap a Begin/End pair and convert that into a Task. I'm trying to write an asynchronous client using HttpWebRequest and tasks on .NET 4.0 (so await is not an option).

My problem is that the return type of `FromAsync` is a Task itself which prevents me from using it in a `ContinueWith` method (`ContinueWith` expects the return type and wraps the data itself in a `Task` object).

Here is the code I have so far, which yields the correct functional result, but is not truly asynchronous:

```
public Task<string> GetHttpRequest(string url, string contentType)
{
    var httpWebRequest = CreateHttpWebRequest(url, "GET", contentType);
    Task<WebResponse> httpTask = Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(httpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse, httpWebRequest.EndGetResponse, null);

    return httpTask.ContinueWith(httpAntecedent =>
          {
              WebResponse webResponse = httpAntecedent.Result;
              Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
              byte[] data = new byte[webResponse.ContentLength];

              var streamReadTask = Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(responseStream.BeginRead, responseStream.EndRead, data, 0, data.Length, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);

              return streamReadTask.ContinueWith(parent =>
                  {
                      responseStream.Close();
                      webResponse.Close();

                      return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
                  });
          }).Result;
}
```

Comment: `return Task.WhenAll(t, t2);` Task.WhenAll hasn't such overload.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Sure it does, that's because it's a `params` method (at least on .Net 4.5, on 4.0, there is no `WhenAll()` at all).

Comment: You can use `await` on .Net 4.0, if you use VS2012 and [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To rephrase your question, you have `Task<Task<string>>` and you want to get `Task<string>` from that, without synchronously waiting for the `Task` to complete.

In C# 5.0, you could do this by using double `await`: `return await await task;`.

Without C# 5.0, you can use [`Unwrap()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd781129.aspx), it does exactly what you want: `return task.Unwrap();`.

If, for some reason, you wanted to do this by yourself, you could use `ContinueWith()` inside `ContinueWith()` together with `TaskCompletionSource`.

---

But your code is flawed: it assumes that you will get the whole response in a single read. That's not guaranteed at all, and in fact won't work correctly quite often. Doing this properly would require more complicated code and probably also `TaskCompletionSource`.

Comment: Thanks @svick. Unwrap was exactly what I was looking for. I introduced a loop to read the entire response properly though as you suggested and that changed the structure of the code significantly (I no longer need the unwrap!)